# AS3 - Unable to resize Image width and height

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem that when I load image it doesn't resize to the value I set in my button, so the button resize itself to fill the image, i think!

And when I see value like  200,200 the resulted image is like 3-4 times bigger than 100,100

```
public function MyButton()
{// this is ctor
   ImageLoader = new Loader();
   addChild(ImageContainer);
}
public function SetWidthAndHeight(newWidth: Number, newHeight: Number): void
{
    width = newWidth;
    height = newHeight;
    //ImageContainer is a MovieClip inside the button
    ImageContainer.height = newHeight;
    ImageContainer.width = newWidth;
}
public function LoadImage(address: String): void
{    
   
    ImageLoader.load(new URLRequest(address));
}
```

I set the value like

```
 var g_newButton = new MyButton();
 g_newButton.ImageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, OnCompleteHandler);**strong text**

 g_newButton.SetWidthAndHeight(100,100);
 g_newButton.LoadImage("myImage.jpg");
function OnCompleteHandler(loadEvent: Event) 
{   
     //g_newButton.ImageLoader.content is always null
    trace("button width " +g_newButton.width);
    trace("button height " +g_newButton.height);
    g_newButton.ImageContainer.addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
    addChild(g_newButton);
}
```

when I run, these are the values I get

> button width 750
>
> button height 385.55

so Why i am not getting

> button width 100
>
> button height 100
> what should i do to make the image resize to fill a button or to have the same size of the button

Comment: Because when you set the **ImageContainer**'s width and height, it **ALSO** affects its parent (which is the **MyButton** instance) width and height, which is **AFTER** you set them to 100, 100.

Comment: the problem was with loading the image and it's fixed, but I wonder as part of my fix, I removed addChild(ImageContainer),
so are you saying that setting a child dimensions propagate to it's parent? so I only need to set the dimensions  to the most inner child? this will set the parent size will the same values??

Comment: If you have a set of in-laid containers with only the innermost having any substance (graphics), and all of them scaled to 100%, and none of them is rotated, then yes, setting the dimensions for the innermost content object will set the same width and height for every of the containers.